# Is there a way to give initial velocity or force to the model in the gazebo?

Tags: ros2

Operating environment
ROS 2 Humble
Ignition Gazebo (Fortress)
SDF version 1.8

I wanna move the cylinder without power on the Ignition Gazebo.
e.g. How to give speed information to objects without wheels or links, etc.

Thank you for your cooperation.[image]